# Jquery hide all but last four digits in text field on page load / immediately

Tags: jquery, hide, textfield, mask

I have a script that successfully hides all but the last four digits of a 9-digit number on blur, after the user inputs their data. I need to adapt it for a second use. I want to be able to dynamically call the 9-digit number entered from one form into a new text field in another form (I can do this much), but I want the first five digits to be hidden immediately on page load, rather than after user focuses on the field, then leaves the field. This is so we can display the last four of a user's social in a second form, after they entered their social in the first form. Here's my current script:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var retrieveValue = function (ev) {
        var $this = $(this),
            val = $this.data(‘value’);

        if (val) {
            $this.val(val);
        }
    },
    hideValue = function (ev) {
        var $this = $(this);

        $this.data(‘value’, $this.val());
        $this.val(function (idx, val) {
            var mask = val.match(/^(.*?)(d{4})$/);

            return (mask[1] ? mask[1].replace(/d/g, ‘ * ’) : ”) + (mask[2] ? mask[2] : ”)
        });
    };

    $(‘#field_a7afui’).focus(retrieveValue);

    $(‘#field_a7afui’).blur(hideValue);

    $(‘#form_hv3hcs’).submit(function (ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        retrieveValue.call($(‘#field_a7afui’)[0], ev);
        alert($(‘#field_a7afui’).val());
        hideValue.call($(‘#field_a7afui’)[0], ev);
    });
})();
```

And here's a jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/d5KaJ/53/

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I question why you are sending back sensitive data in the first place?
Security through obscurity is no security at all.

Comment: Thanks for the new slogan.

Comment: And in answer to your question, I'm not doing anything. I'm designing a site, and figuring out how to do security. This was one attempted step in the process.

Comment: [Kerckhoffs principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs%27s_principle)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transferring a user's SSN between forms on the client side presents security concerns.  You should look into storing the SSN on the server and having the server return something like `*****1234` to load into other forms.

Comment: That makes sense. I'll call that an answer! Thanks.